# Duply adds an AT (@) before the path (Ubuntu 16)

Tags: backup, duplicity, duply

After an update from Ubuntu 14 to Ubuntu 16, `duply` stopped working - or rather continued working, but stored the backup files into the wrong directory.

This is the duply configuration (excerpt):

```
TARGET='file:///mnt/backup/server'
TARGET_USER=''
TARGET_PASS=''
```

And here's what `ps -aux` tells me when the backup is started:

```
python2 /usr/bin/duplicity --name duply_server --encrypt-key XXXXXXXX --sign-key XXXXXXXX --verbosity 4 --full-if-older-than 14D --force --exclude-filelist /root/.duply/server/exclude / file://@/mnt/backup/server
```

Note that AT sign (@) in the filename (last parameter). When run from `/root/`, It causes `duplicity` to create a folder `/root/@/mnt/backup/server` to store the backup there. I am unsure if this is a change in the behavior of duply, duplicity or python. Any idea how to solve this and tell duply the full folder, as it used to work?

**Edit**

For now, I assume, it's a bug in duply which tries to add a user name to the folder, as required for ftp.

My workaround is to create a symbolic link `/root/@/mnt` -> `/mnt`, but that's nothing more than a workaround. So thank you very much for better ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a bug that was fixed with

> 2.0.2 (23.05.2017)
>   - bugfix: never insert creds into file:// targets

you can get the latest version from http://duply.net.

..ede/duply.net

Comment: Thanks for solving this puzzle. I cannot belief that the Ubuntu repositories still contain the buggy version...